# Is the word 'stroke' understood, in meaning one of these / \?

Tags: american-english, offensive-language

All the meanings of the word 'slash', other than an oblique forward or backward stroke are either violent or obscene. They include cuts made with swords, lashing with a whip, cutting maliciously car tyres with a knife, and in Britain the act of male urination (I have never heard it applied to a female).

Hence I find the word when used in its now everyday sense of a small inoffensive printed stroke (which is American in origin) unpleasantly resonant. I tend therefore to use the time-honoured British nomenclature of *stroke*, *forward stroke*, and *backward stroke*. Does everyone understand that?

Comment: I think to avoid the downvotes, you may want to change your question to a more 'probing' form. Perhaps _When did slash start to mean '/', when did it start to mean urinate and why (if they do) do Brits use 'stroke' for '/ \' more than slash. (or something like that). I suspect the DV is for _this is more like a discussion than an answerable question_ possibly. I'd be interested in the _slash / urination_ history .

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it appears to be peeving in the form of a question.

Comment: In phrases like "Subsection 3, paragraph 5, revision 3 stroke B", when delivered in a British accent (plummy RP is best), _stroke_ will usually be understood as **/** in the US. Otherwise it's unlikely. But there are [many other `SL-` words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/sl.pdf) with the "2-Dimensional Contact" sense; and [the `STR-` words](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/str.pdf) are interesting, too.

Comment: Discussion moved [to a chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16405/discussion-on-question-by-ws2-is-the-word-stroke-understood-in-meaning-one-of) for your convenience. Please don't **discuss** in comments.

Answer (score 5):

> stroke
>
> strōk/
>
> noun: stroke; plural noun: strokes
>
> 1. an act of hitting or striking someone or something; a blow. "he received three strokes of the cane"
>
>    synonyms: blow, hit, thump, punch, slap, smack, cuff, knock;

[(from Google)](https://www.google.ca/search?q=define:stroke)

Your replacement word is just as violent as the word you wish to replace. As a Canadian I can tell you that I would find it difficult to understand you if you constantly referred to `/` as *stroke*.

Comment: You're tempting fate with 'from Google' there! But I think you're being a bit hard on _stroke_. There's lots of nice things _stroke_ can help you with; rowing, swimming, snooker, cricket, hair, painting, pornography and there's some evidence that [stroking a pussy](http://www.examiner.com/article/five-reasons-for-why-having-a-cat-can-help-reduce-your-stress) can help you live longer.

Comment: @Frank well, yeah, there are lots of other definitions for _stroke_, including [the kind that causes brain damage](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stroke). My point was that words can have multiple meanings and the fact that _slash_ connotes something violent to WS2 doesn't mean it does to everyone, and _stroke_ has similar problems.